# problems with .change(function() javascript in ie<9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

i have problems with this script in ie<9. what problems with my script? thanks

ie7,8 error: SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
             jquery.js, line 3 character 32369

in jquery.js: function(a){this.parentNode.insertBefore(a,this.nextSibling)};

```
            $(":radio[name=variant]").change(function() {
            var vat = $(this).val()
                /*$(this).parent().parent().find('td.cost').css("display", "none");
                $("#costVariants_"+val).css("display", "block");
                */
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('label.variant_color').css("border", "none");
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span.price').css("display", "none");
            $("#color_"+vat).css("border", "1px solid white") ;
            /*$("#price_"+vat).css("display", "block") ;*/
            $("#price_"+vat).insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().find('.main_image'));
            $(this).parent().find('.main_image').html($(this).parent().find('span.price').html());
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.main_image').html($(this).parent().parent().find('span.price').html());
            });
```

and i'm sorry, this is my first post here. thanks a lot

Comment: At first glance .. You're missing a ; on line 2.  Beyond that, all the parent() calls doesn't look so hot.  Surely there's a more graceful way.  Have markup?

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i read some docs, and now i'm try allways avoid .parent.
But in general my problem was in hiden . ie<9 can't select label (the label of input was a color block in my project), when the input is hiden (display: none;)